# Class based view to function based view

Tags: django-views, django-rest-framework

How can I convert a **class based view**, which is used for creating **REST API** to a **function based view**

my input class view

```
class
Login_View_Sets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     queryset = Login_Model.objects.all()
     serializer_class = Login_Serializer()
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: which is the part that you send response?

Comment: I didn't created it. Is that necessary for send and receive json data ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Django REST framework tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#pulling-it-all-together) shows an example of a function based view for an entry point. You'll have to adjust things so it matches your model and serializer.

Comment: Can I get **request. body()** using class based views ?

Comment: How does this relate to the question ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, which I meant

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')
```

In a class-based view, this would become:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer.

This is an example of function based view view

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
    # <view logic>
    return HttpResponse('result')
```

In a class-based view, this would become:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')
```